# discord.py: does not calculate if not member

Tags: discord.py

every time I run the command not quoting the member it doesn't calculate `if not member` and I don't know why ...

Code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member,arg='Motivo non specificato'):
    if not member:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name="Per favore specifica l'utente!",
            icon_url="'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'"
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    role = get(member.guild.roles, id=int("691009285634654229"))
    if (ctx.author == member):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare te stesso!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Mutato'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
           color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'{member.display_name} è attualmente mutato',
            icon_url=f'{member.avatar_url}'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Triumvirato'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare un triumviro!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Co-Triumvirato'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare un co triumviro!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Presidente ad Interim del LMII'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare il presidente!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Moderatori'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare un moderatore!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=discord.Colour.green()
    )
    embed.set_author(
        name=f'{member.display_name} è stato mutato',
        icon_url=f'{member.avatar_url}'
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Motivo: {arg}')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=discord.Colour.gold()
    )
    embed.set_author(
         name=f'{ctx.author._user} ha mutato {member._user}',
         icon_url=f'{member.avatar_url}'
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Motivo: {arg}')
    embed.add_field(
        name='Utente mutato:',
        value=f'{member._user}',
    inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Mutato da:',
        value=f'{ctx.author._user}',
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Durata:',
        value='∞',
        inline=True
    )
    channel = client.get_channel(729553772547932190)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name="Non ti è permesso mutare",
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
```

Comment: Make `member` default to `None`, member : Member = None. Otherwise the command throws a MissingRequiredArgument error.

Comment: I did but nothing has changed

Comment: Instead of checking “if not member”, check if member is equal to the default value.

Comment: done but nothing changes ...
I used `if member == None:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if not member:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name="Per favore specifica l'utente!",
            icon_url="'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'"
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
```

The problem was a syntax error, an extra character that didn't make the command go.
[image]